# A problem about polynomial in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ be a prime.

If $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{r} a_{i} x^{i}$ and $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{s} b_{i} x^{i}$ be polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$ such that $f(x)g(x)=0$ ,

**(1)** $a_{i} b_{j} =0$,for  all $i,j$

**(2)** $a_{i} b_{j} \neq 0$,for  some  $i,j$

My try, $a_{1} b_{1}=0 $

Either $a_1=0$ or $b_1=0$ or they are divisor of zero.

Then $a_{1} b_{2}+a_{2} b_{1}=0 $

Now, if $a_1=0$, then $a_{2} b_{1}=0 $

After, $a_{1} b_{3}+a_{2} b_{2}+a_{2} b_{3} = 0 $

If, $a_1=0$ then $a_{2} b_{2}+a_{2} b_{3} = 0 $

My thought here, if $\mathbb{Z_{p^n}}$ is $\mathbb{Z_2} $ here, then, I think option **(2)** is true if we take all of $a_2,b_2,b_3$ non zero.

But is option **(1)** the answer?

I am really in doubt here.

Please anyone help!

Comment: No, please see the definition of $f(x),g(x)$

Comment: How can $(1)$ and $(2)$ both be true?

Comment: @Derek Luna No, only one option is true,,, I doubt my process,, that's why there is a doubt about option **(1)**, so, may be option **(1)** is wrong. That's why I want help ,as I am in doubt.